# How to use PHPSpreadsheet in CodeIgniter 3 to read data from Excel (.xlsx and .xls) file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

Recently in one of my CodeIgniter based project, I need to read data from Excel file ( .xlsx and .xls ) and insert those data into MySQL. Unfortunately, I did not use **PHPSpreadsheet** before (as I did not require to work with Excel :( ).

So far what I did was, download the **PHPSpreadsheet** from Github and extract it to the root directory of my **CodeIgniter** Project.

[image]
PHPSpreadsheet in CodeIgniter root directory.

[image]
File Structure of PHPSpreadsheet.

So far I've tried to import the official docs example into my CI apps:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
    class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
       function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();
       }

       public function index()
       {
           $inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
           $inputFileName = 'test.xlsx';
           $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    /**  Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
          $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
          print_r( $spreadsheet );
    }
}
```

But it shows the following error!!
[image]

Can anyone tell me how can I use **PHPSpreadsheet** in **CodeIgniter** to read data from Excel file and store them into MySQL database?

- Thanks

Comment: You need to autoload the library using a psr4 autoloader like the one from fig if you google. You cannot load namespaces libraries as you would a ci library.

Comment: Did you use Composer to install? It is easiest if you do.

Comment: Thanks, @DFriend

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to include PhpSpreadsheet is to use Composer - the documentation at [https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) explains how to do this.

Otherwise you will need a PSR4 autoloader to load the class specified by your use statement or to include the files yourself. If you include files yourself, to read an Excel file you will need to include PhpSpreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/IOFactory.php

Comment: I am sorry but the link you provided appears to be dead.

Comment: Since the link is dead just Google 'phpspreadsheet'.