# I want to change worksheet excel direction for Right-To-Left by the code

Tags: excel, codeigniter, phpexcel

This code doesn't change the direction.

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setRightToLeft(true);
```

Comment: In Excel, the VBA command would be `ActiveSheet.DisplayRightToLeft = True`, not sure how that would translate to codeigniter or php

Answer (score 0):

The code you used looks correct.

PHPExcel is an old library. The new library is PhpSpreadsheet. I have include PhpSpreadsheet in CodeIgniter 3 in the `third_party` folder. See also

- [How to use PHPSpreadsheet in CodeIgniter 3 to read data from Excel (.xlsx and .xls) file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648908/how-to-use-phpspreadsheet-in-codeigniter-3-to-read-data-from-excel-xlsx-and-x/48661264)
- [What are the main differences between PHPExcel and PhpSpreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117762/what-are-the-main-differences-between-phpexcel-and-phpspreadsheet)